# table is specified twice both as a target for INSERT and as separate source of data

Tags: mysql, sql

I made this query but it gave me error just like in the title

```
INSERT INTO data_waktu_vaksinasi (id_binatang, id_vaksin, tanggal_vaksin, status_vaksin) VALUES 
    (1, 1, (SELECT DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) FROM data_waktu_vaksinasi, 'belum')
```

Comment: Doesn't this work? `INSERT INTO data_waktu_vaksinasi (id_binatang, id_vaksin, tanggal_vaksin, status_vaksin) VALUES 
    (1, 1, (SELECT DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) FROM data_waktu_vaksinasi), 'belum')`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i've tried to run it on phpmyadmin, but it gave me error that the table is specified twice

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44970574/798677

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL *does* allow the same table to be used for the source and target for `inserts`.  You just need to use the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO data_waktu_vaksinasi (id_binatang, id_vaksin, tanggal_vaksin, status_vaksin) 
     SELECT 1, 1, DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), 'belum'
     FROM data_waktu_vaksinasi;
```

Comment: @LiaDianti . . . I don't understand the question.  Perhaps you should ask another question with example data to explain what you want.

Comment: so I want to insert multiple data at the same time with this query, like this INSERT INTO data_waktu_vaksinasi (id_binatang, id_vaksin, tanggal_vaksin, status_vaksin) VALUES 
 ('$id', 1, SELECT 1, 1, DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '$status'),
 ('$id', 2, SELECT 1, 1, DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '$status'),
 ('$id', 3, SELECT 1, 1, DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '$status')

but it still gave me error

Answer (score 3):

Put the source table in `subquery` to fix this problem. `Mysql` does not allow same table in source and target for `DML` operation's

```
INSERT INTO data_waktu_vaksinasi 
            (id_binatang, 
             id_vaksin, 
             tanggal_vaksin, 
             status_vaksin) 
SELECT 1, 
       1, 
       dt, 
       'belum' 
FROM   (SELECT Date_add(Max(tanggal_vaksin), interval 1 year) AS dt 
        FROM   data_waktu_vaksinasi)a
```

Comment: Alas, this answer is not correct.  MySQL does not permit references to the same table for `update` and `delete`.  It does permit references to the same table for `insert`.

Comment: Oops, I should add the code *is* correct, just overly complicated.

Answer (score 2):

**Try** this code

```
INSERT INTO data_waktu_vaksinasi
(id_binatang, id_vaksin, tanggal_vaksin, status_vaksin)
VALUES
    (
        1,
        1,
        (
            SELECT date FROM
                (SELECT DATE_ADD(max(tanggal_vaksin), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) date
                 FROM data_waktu_vaksinasi, 'belum') subquery
        )
    )
```

I didn't test *this* code, **but** I **tested an equivalent code** (also an `INSERT INTO` statement with same table in subquery as in master-query)

**The trick**

is the *wrap* the subquery with the same table into another subquery, that only queries the columns from the `SELECT`-clause of the actual subquery.

**Result: Mysql doesn't complain**

> I don't know why this works
>  It seems to me kina like cheating