# Trying to update a table with a value from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE seasons SET good=good+1 WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM seasons ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

When I run this command I get the error:

> #1093 - Table 'seasons' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970574/table-is-specified-twice-both-as-a-target-for-update-and-as-a-separate-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MySQL limitation.

One method is to use `JOIN`.  However, for this it is probably better to use `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`:

```
UPDATE seasons s 
    SET s.good = s.good + 1 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

This does assume that `id` is not duplicated in the table, but that seems like a reasonable assumption for a column called `id`.

Comment: I read about the workaround of using an alias for the table in the update part of the query to fix the issue. Is it a valid option as far as you know? Never tried since I never had the issue before