# MySQL table was specified twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why I got an error when try to execute this query:

```
UPDATE ordersperformers AS t1 SET t1.Status = 1 
where not exists (
SELECT 1 FROM ordersperformers 
   WHERE ordersperformers.Orders_Id = 3 
    AND (ordersperformers.Status = 1 OR ordersperformers.Status = 2))
    AND t1.Orders_Id = 3 AND t1.Users_Id = 5;
```

Why MySQL does not realize that I work with table `ordersperformers`?

Error is:

> `#1093 - Table 't1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data`.

If execute query:

```
UPDATE ordersperformers SET Status = 1 
where  ordersperformers.Status NOT IN (1,2)
AND Orders_Id = 3;
```

It will update anyway one row:

[image]

But I dont need update any rows cause table with `Orders_Id = 3` has one row with `Status = 1`

Comment: I faced with this problem it a lot of my queries, I dont have problems if run this query in SQL Database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970574/table-is-specified-twice-both-as-a-target-for-update-and-as-a-separate-source)

Comment: use `select * from table` inside that query after update rather `as table` in order to avoid this mysql confusion as per the reference link above

Comment: Can you show this?

Comment: please refer the link in the above comment check the corrected answer hope that helps

Comment: I dont understend how apply this to my query

Comment: @OPV Have you thought that maybe you did not make clear which rows need to be updated and which not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `EXISTS()` if you want to update Status=1 with same order_id has at least one Status=1. 
Also because we do check with the same table you need put it to `sub-query` (yes, inside the bracket) to avoid conflict.

Simply you need to do something like this :

**SCRIPT EDITED:**

```
UPDATE ordersperformers as O1 
SET O1.Status = 1 
where  EXISTS 
            (SELECT 1
             FROM (select * from ordersperformers) AS O2
             WHERE O1.Orders_Id = O2.Orders_Id
             AND O2.Status = 1
             )
```

Comment: I have some rows with `Orders_Id` and `sers_Id`. I need update only if in table there is Status = 1 OR 2 for only `Orders_Id`

Comment: That is incorrect I need use only `where Orders_Id = 3 ` Not `AND Users_Id = 5;`.

Comment: @OPV Ok. Remove User_Id=5 from the filter.

Comment: It again find row with `Status 0`, but I need update if there are not rows in table for `Orders_Id` where `Status = 1` altogether

Comment: @OPV Could you select the table first please. What you see when you execute "select Status from ordersperformers where order_id=3"?

Comment: I added result to question and explanation

Comment: @OPV Ok. Order_Id is not unique and you want to update the other rows as status=1 if at least one of the same Order_Id has Status=1. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, therefor I tried check this using where exists

Comment: @OPV Ok. I have edited the query with using EXISTS()

Comment: `Unknown column 'O1.Order_Id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I need `where not  EXISTS `

Comment: @OPV Change the Order_Id to Orders_ID.

Comment: `#1093 - Table 'O1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data`

Comment: @OPV Probably we use same table in exists. I put it to sub-query.