# Using HAVING in UPDATE with WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

i am trying to update a table by setting column VAT TO 2 where we have duplicate values in column image

```
SET 
    VAT = 2
WHERE id >0  
 HAVING count(image) > 1
```

Comment: i simply want to update VAT where there are duplicate values in image column

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: What's `image`'s type?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment to a previous answer I assume that you use MySql.
In MySql you need to join the table to a query that returns the duplicate images:

```
update tablename t inner join (
  select image   
  from tablename
  where id > 0
  group by image
  having count(*) > 1
) i on i.image = t.image
set vat = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
UPDATE applicantinfo
SET VAT = 2
WHERE image IN (
    SELECT image
    FROM (SELECT * FROM applicantinfo)
    WHERE id > 0
    GROUP BY image
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

`SELECT` inside the `WHERE` clause supplies duplicate `image`s of rows with `id`s above zero.

Comment: Table 'applicantinfo' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: applicantinfo is MyTable in your query

Comment: Since this is MySql, [you need to use a little trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44970574/335858). See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this.

For SQL Server

```
update t set t.VAT = 2 from applicantinfo as t inner join
(select Image from applicantinfo group by image having count(*)>1) as b 
on t.image = b.image
```

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. Please mention for which DBMS product this works