# SQL Update table where Relation is inside other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

hello I have two Table where table number one is for product and table two is the category i want to update using the this SQL but keep getting syntax error

```
UPDATE product SET local_delivery = 0,none_local_delivery = 0,
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT product.local_delivery,product.none_local_delivery 
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_to_category ON product.product_id = 
product_to_category.product_id WHERE
product_to_category.category_id = 90 )
```

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT
product.local_delivery,
product.none' at line 4

Comment: There is a comma too many right before `WHERE`.

Comment: removed the comma now (1093 - You can't specify target table 'product' for update in FROM clause)

Comment: Okay, syntax error fixed. I wonder, though, whether the update statement does what you want it to do. If there is a product with category 90 in the table, you'll update all rows. If not, you'll update no rows.

Comment: No, need to update product list where the category id is 90 @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag. Both error messages indicate you are using MySQL, not SQL Server, The error 1093 is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970574/table-is-specified-twice-both-as-a-target-for-update-and-as-a-separate-source/44971214#44971214, but in your case you shouldn't join to the products table in the subquery anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is a comma right before `WHERE`.

Your update statement then updates either all or no rows in the table, depending on whether a product exists for category 90.

I suppose you rather want to update all produts of category 90 instead. In order to achieve that, relate the product_to_category to the product you are updating. If my assumtion is correct, the query will have to look like this:

```
UPDATE product SET local_delivery = 0,none_local_delivery = 0
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM product_to_category 
  WHERE product_to_category.product_id = product.product_id
  AND product_to_category.category_id = 90
);
```

Or a tad simpler with `IN`:

```
UPDATE product SET local_delivery = 0,none_local_delivery = 0
WHERE product_id IN 
        (SELECT product_id FROM product_to_category WHERE category_id = 90);
```

Comment: i used tad simpler with IN and it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use following syntax

```
UPDATE p
SET    local_delivery = 0,
       none_local_delivery = 0
FROM   product AS p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT  1
               FROM   product P
                      INNER JOIN product_to_category PCT
                              ON P.product_id =
                                 PCT.product_id
               WHERE  PCT.category_id = 90);
```

Or following syntax and remove `where exist`

```
UPDATE p
SET    local_delivery = 0,
       none_local_delivery = 0
FROM   product p
       INNER JOIN product_to_category PTC
               ON P.product_id = PTC.product_id
WHERE  product_to_category.category_id = 90
```

Comment: Pointless selecting any columns in an EXISTS

Comment: The reason why its "pointless" is because EXIST does not return columns rather than a "True"  when the "Where"  clause requirements are met in the sub query

Comment: Thanks for your mention. I have corrected it.